# FLUTTER WEB: How To Use Google Places Autocomplete In Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, flutter-web, google-places-autocomplete

I used almost every package for places auto complete, I am getting cross error. Please let me know if there is any way to use places autocomplete In Android, iOS and web together.

```
 var p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
    radius: 500000,
    strictbounds: false,
    region: "in",
    language: "en",
    context: context,
    mode: Mode.overlay,
    apiKey: "key",
    components: [new Component(Component.country, "in")],
    types: ["(cities)"],
    hint: "Search City",
);
```

currently I am using this function

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate api for this google placeAutocomple

```
  var response = await _client.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$input"
          "&types=establishment&language=en&components=country:in&key=$kGoogleApiKey&sessiontoken=19");
```

and then show result in autocomplete textfield or listview.

```
  void getPlaces(input, lng,lat) {
    SearchLocation()
        .getPlaces(input: input, lang: lng,lat: lat)
        .then((value) => _placesResponse(value))
        .catchError((e) => _placesError(e));
  }

  _placesResponse(List<Place> v) {
    setState(() {
      addressList = v;
    });
  }

  _placesError(e) {
    errorSnackbar(context,e.toString());
  }
```

Listview Widget

```
ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: addressList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                      var address = addressList[index];
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            if(_isLoading != true) {
                              getSelectedPlace(address.placeId);
                            }
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      width: 25,
                                      height: 25,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: borderRadiusAll_30),
                                      child: Center(
                                          child: Icon(
                                        CupertinoIcons.location_solid,
                                        size: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ))),
                                  Flexible(
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        address.description ?? '',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.sourceSans3(textStyle: textTheme.bodyText2),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: MyColor.kGrey,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
```

For this you need to have **kGoogleApiKey**

To get lat long u need add [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

```
  Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    setState((){
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();
    if (!hasPermission) {
      Geolocator.requestPermission();
      return;
    }
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best).then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _position = position;
        lang = _position?.longitude.toString() ?? '';
        lat = _position?.latitude.toString() ?? '';
      });
      Log.d("Latitude ${lat} Longitude ${lang}");
      setState((){
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      setState((){
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      warning(context,e.toString());
      Geolocator.requestPermission();
      Log.d('Catch error ${e.toString()}');
    });
  }
```

Comment: how can I pass lat long while searching?

Comment: @PavanPatil edited the answer you can get lat lang by using this method.

Comment: hi kokila can you please provide link to any example?

Comment: @PavanPatil edited api url and u can visit here for google api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=oun&types=establishment&language=en&components=country:in&key="My_key"&sessiontoken=19' from origin 'http://localhost:55987' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.